# Adding Folder/Subfolders/files in Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

How can I add a folder recursively, with its subfolders and its files?

When I use `git add folder_name`, only that folder is getting added.  `git status` now shows the files under the subfolders are shown as new files and untracked.

For example, in Rails application, inside the Rails project folder, there are many folders:

- app
- public
- db
- script
- vendor
- etc.

Is there a better way to add a rails project to git?

Comment: have you tried adding `folder_name/.` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
cd desired_directory; git add .;
```

Er, it looks like this was answered by Justin L. in a comment while I as typing.

Comment: Wait, `cd foo; git add .` has a different result from `git add foo`?

Comment: @Jefromi: apparently it has. `git add foo/.` would be the same though. Although the phrase "a leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to add `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to add all files in the directory, recursively." in the `git add` man page seems to contradict that.

Comment: @VonC: Well I've never had any trouble adding directories recursively with the obvious `git add foo` method - can't manage to reproduce the OP's problem.